# Is it possible to combine will_paginate with find_by_sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, find-by-sql

In my Rails application I want to use the `will_paginate` gem to paginate on my SQL query. Is that possible? I tried doing something like this but it didn't work:

```
@users = User.find_by_sql("
    SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
     CASE 
      WHEN r.user_accepted =1 AND (r.friend_accepted =0 || r.friend_accepted IS NULL)
       .........").paginate(
                  :page => @page, :per_page => @per_page, 
                  :conditions => conditions_hash,
                  :order => 'first_name ASC')
```

If not, can you recommend a way around this? I don't want to have to write my own pagination.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `paginate_by_sql`, i.e.

```
sql = " SELECT * 
        FROM   users
        WHERE  created_at >= ?
        ORDER  BY created_at DESC "

@users = User.paginate_by_sql(
  [sql, 2.weeks.ago],
  page: @page,
  per_page: @per_page
)
```

As a general rule any finder can be paginated by replacing the `find*` with `paginate*`.

Comment: With binds: `paginate_by_sql([sql, binds], page: # etc..`

Answer (score -2):

> User.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
@users = User.find_by_sql 
@users = @users.paginate
```

What will_paginate and rails version are you using?

Comment: In your solution, pagination is applied on the result set returned by the `find_by_sql`. So you might have to deal with a large result-set and hence the system has to perform redundant computing.